# Database Schema - Groups, Subgroups, Users and Achievements

Tags: database, schema, achievements, usergroups

I asked something similar some days ago, but, something changed now. In the last question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181722/how-to-build-a-user-group-achievement-database)) I wanted to know how to make a database that could hold data for groups, users and achievements, but now I need to know how to do that, but also adding subgroups.

Here are the rules (change them if you think it's better):

- Groups can have multiple subgroups
- Sub-Groups can have multiple users
- Users can have multiple groups
- Users can have multiple subgroups
- Users can have multiple Achievements
- Every user is in the "Main" subgroup
- Achievements can have multiple subgroups

I have even more issues in this case because I don't know how to treat the subgroups and groups, and how I should relate achievements to the rest of the database.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think i found a way to do this. I'll treat subgroups as normal groups (with achievements and users) and the group's table will be used to connect every subgroup in the same main group.

Comment: Could you please explain this answer in more depth. This is absolutely no clear explanation.